# NFC-Tagtype isn't supported

Tags: nfc

I've got a Samsung Galaxy S6 and recently updated my software to Android 7.0. Ever since I updated my Samsung Galaxy S6, my NFC Tag reader apps stopped working. Is this a known issue? I've tried multiple cards, but my phone refuses to read tags anymore.

Any ideas what I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand Samsung got rid of "S Beam" in favor of the stock "Android Beam" in the 7.0 update which affects NFC. Check your Android Beam settings and if it's on try with it off and vice versa if it was off.

Comment: I've tried both options, but neither seem to work. Is there a way to get S Beam back?